# Calling OracleProcedure from VB.NET

Tags: oracle, vb.net, plsql, oracle-manageddataaccess

Oracle procedure call from vb.net code is working fine if I use "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" dll. Rewriting same procedure call using "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" giving error. What am I doing wrong -
Error message : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

**Code using- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data:**

```
Dim db As Database = GetDatabase("connection string")
Dim dbCommand As DbCommand
dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("procedurename")
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "piv_userid", DbType.String, strUserID)
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "piv_userpwd", DbType.String, strPassword)
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "piv_appstub", DbType.String, My.Application.Info.ProductName)
db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "pon_error_no", DbType.Decimal, 10)
db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "pov_error_msg", DbType.String, 400)
db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "pov_applist", DbType.String, 100)
db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand)
```

**code using - OracleManagedDataAccess.dll**

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection("connection string")
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("procedurename", conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("piv_userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = strUserID
cmd.Parameters.Add("piv_userpwd", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = strPassword
cmd.Parameters.Add("piv_appstub", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = My.Application.Info.ProductName

cmd.Parameters.Add("pon_error_no", OracleDbType.Decimal, 10, ParameterDirection.Output)
cmd.Parameters.Add("pov_error_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 400, ParameterDirection.Output)
cmd.Parameters.Add("pov_applist", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, ParameterDirection.Output)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Error message : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Comment: Do you have the entire error stack? Most likely it's something within the stored procedure, and you'll need the full error stack to get a line number and dig into the code to find out what's wrong. If you find the line number points to the pov_error_msg := or pov_applist := assignments to the OUT parameters, then you'll know that you haven't allotted a large enough client variable to receive these outputs. But it could be on some other line and be unrelated to how you are calling it.

Comment: As for the reason it works with one driver and not the other, you may want to look at whether DBType.String and OracleDbType.Varchar2 specify their sizes in bytes, or in characters. If you DB is a multibyte character set, you may be getting more bytes than characters, and a possible difference in what the sizes mean to those respective drivers could cause one to fail and the other not.

Answer (score 0):

For output parameter I always use this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("pon_error_no", OracleDbType.Decimal, 10,  ParameterDirection.Output)
cmd.Parameters("pon_error_no").DbType = DbType.Decimal

cmd.Parameters.Add("pov_error_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 400, Nothing, ParameterDirection.Output)    
cmd.Parameters("pov_error_msg").DbType = DbType.String

cmd.Parameters.Add("pov_applist", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, Nothing, ParameterDirection.Output)
cmd.Parameters("pov_applist").DbType = DbType.String

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```